# Making footer widgets re-size to the same height

Tags: jquery, css, footer

I am working on a wordpres site (with genesis). I need to make it so that the footer areas re-size automatically, if the site admin decides to change the size of the image in one of the footers.

I have some jquery code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
'use strict';
// Get current browser width
var browserWidth = jQuery(window).width();

// Responsive: Get Width
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    browserWidth = jQuery(this).width();

    // Set size of footer-widgets-*
    selectorSizing( browserWidth );
});

/*
 * Resizes the selector to the designated size
 *
 * @param int    size     Browser Size to do nothing
 * @param string selector Selector, defaults to '#footer-widgets .widget-area'
 */
function selectorSizing( size, selector ) {

    var heights = [];

    // selector as optional argument
    if ( !selector)
        var selector = '.footer-widgets ';

    // size is required
    if ( !size)
        return false;

    // Responsive Code
    // Widgets move to 100% width if width of the browser window is < 300px
    // Done via @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) { } in style.css
    if( 300 < size ) {
        jQuery(selector).each( function( index, value ) {
            heights[index] = jQuery(this).height();
        });

        // Set max height
        var max = Math.max.apply( Math, heights );

        // Assign max height to the footer-widgets
        jQuery(selector).each( function( index, value ) {
            jQuery(this).height(max);
        });
    }
    else {
        // Remove max height to the footer-widgets
        jQuery(selector).each( function( index, value ) {
            jQuery(this).height('auto');
        });
    }
}

selectorSizing( browserWidth );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d4q05to6/8/

**UPDATE:** I want to make both the yellow boxes the same height. If the site user decides to change the image or one that is bigger/smaller, then both of the yellow boxes need to adjust so that they are the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For desktop version of the website, one option is to make your footer behave as a table using display table variants in CSS.

```
.footer-widgets{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer-widgets .wrap{
    display: table-row;
}
.footer-widgets .wrap .widget-area{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4q05to6/9/) for the same

Comment: Thank-you so much for that. I need to make this work on a responsive site though.

Comment: The responsive style can stay as is, where the three or two widgets lie in 3 rows with width 100%.

At the breakpoint of 300px, you can have .footer-widget as display:block and also the wrap and widget-area classes as display block, that'll make sure it is attaining full device width.

This will also remove your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it should be responsive. You can adjust the media queries breakpoints to match your template.

Here if you want a fluid footer you need to remove the fixed `width` of your widget areas and use a percentage based width. Also adjust parent and child elements accordingly.

see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d4q05to6/20/) - try to resize the window

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for both yellow boxes to be the same height. So if the site user replaces the current image with one smaller/ larger, then both the yellow boxes adjust and are the same height.

Comment: then give your .widget-area a fixed height but you will need to take into consideration the different breakpoints and content inside and adjust the height to your need. you may want to give it a height:auto on small devices then the height will adjust according to the content - see demo updated

Comment: Thanks, but I can't give .widget-area a fixed height, as this is part of a wordpress site & the user may decide to replace the image with a bigger image. I need  the height to adjust, but for both yellow boxes to adjust to the same height.